# How to clear a div with use of Jquery instead of calling directly on document

Tags: jquery, html, dom

How can I clear my div with jQuery?

Is the problem that I miss something before I can use `innerHTML`? 
I know jQuery used the document.getElementById under the hood, so I could and maybe just should just call directly on the document, but for know I just want to know what is the my problem and how to solve it.

This works and clear the div:

```
document.getElementById('someId').innerHTML = "";
```

This doesn't work and don't clear the div:

```
$("#someId").innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#someId")` returns a jQuery wrapper object which does not have `.innerHTML` property, you can use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html) instead

```
$("#someId").html("");
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$("#someId")[0].innerHTML = "";
```

`$("#someId")` is jQuery Object so you can not use `innerHTML` directly.

`$("#someId")[0]` JavaScript object as jQuery selector returns an array.

or

[**.html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html)

```
$("#someId").html('');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#someId").html("");
```

reference **[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try using the html() method instead:

```
$("#someId").html('');
```